# How to partition one list into a smaller list

Tags: java, optimization, lambda

I'm currently working on a project where I have the following

```
    for (String x : listOne) {
        for (String y : listOne) {
            for (String z : listTwo) {
                if (x.noun1.equal(z.noun1) && y.noun2.equals(z.noun2)) {
                    doSomething();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where listOne and listTwo are just `ArrayList<String>`s. Both `ArrayList`s hold verb:noun:noun pairs where we have a verb at index 0, a noun at index 1 a noun at index 2 (and so on).

This is essentially just a brute force search algorithm. 
In an attempt to optimize the search process I want to create a smaller list of triples of x's that have the same noun 1 as z and a smaller list of triples of y's that have the same noun two as z. I don't really know anything about lambda expressions in java but after some research, I'm sure theres a way to do this using lambdas in java.

Any help on how I'd go about doing this, or any articles that might be of use would be appreciated.

Edit: Here's an example

```
ArrayList<String> al1 = "IsA","Car","Vehicle","IsA","house","building"..
ArrayList<String> al2 = "IsA","house","home"..
```

Since `al1`s noun 1 at index 4 equals `al2`s noun 1 at index 1. We'd return a new ArrayList or Map that contains "IsA","house""building".

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide an example?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou it's just pseudo-code above. In my actual project I'm checking if (arrayList1@i.equals arrayList2@j){ doSomething(); } where i and j start at 1 and jump 3 indices at a time

Comment: What is `x.noun1`? To my understanding `x` is a string, it shouldn't have a property named `noun1`. Why don't you create a `Triplet` class that holds your verb:noun:noun strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've linked your previous question, otherwise it's rather impossible to understand what you want. IIUYC you're asking for the conversion of your tricolor-list to a list of triples. That's pretty simple:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public static class Triplet {
    public static List<Triplet> listFrom(List<String> strings) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(strings.size() % 3 == 0);
        final List<Triplet> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<strings.size(); i+=3) {
            result.add(new Triplet(
                    strings.get(i), strings.get(i+1), strings.get(i+2)));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public final String verb;
    public final String noun1;
    public final String noun2;
}
```

The above annotations are from [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org) and do exactly what they say. If you don't want to use Lombok, then write what's needed manually.

---

That's actually all, but I'll expand on the previous question. Above there was no use for lambdas, now you get two.

You prepare your data like

```
final List<Triplet> tripletsOne = Triplet.listFrom(listOne);
final List<Triplet> tripletsTwo = Triplet.listFrom(listTwo);
final Map<String, List<Triplet>> mapOneByNoun1 = tripletsOne.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.noun1));
final Map<Object, List<Triplet>> mapOneByNoun2 = tripletsOne.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.noun2));
final List<Triplet> EMPTY = Collections.emptyList();
```

This was simpler than my previous approach thanks to [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

As `z` occurs in both conditions, it makes sense to use it in the outermost loop

```
for (final Triplet z : tripletsTwo) {
    for (final Triplet x : mapOneByNoun1.getOrDefault(z.noun1, EMPTY)) {
        for (final Triplet y : mapOneByNoun2.getOrDefault(z.noun2, EMPTY)) {
            doSomething(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks a million. Really appreciate it. The only thing is could you explain what groupingBy(t -> t.noun1) is doing. Its showing as an error in the code, just so I know how to correct it

Comment: @JohnMeehan Currently, the support for lambdas is still weak, even trivial errors like a missing parenthesis makes Eclipse helpless und useless. I copied the code in my Eclipse, fixed a few trivial things and updated the answer. `Preconditions` are from Guava, highly recommended, but for new, you can leave it out. Now it compiles... and probably also works.

Comment: @JohnMeehan `Collectors.groupingBy` partitions the list into a Map, just like I did in the other answer, see `Addendum -yBuckets` there. And read the Javadoc, it's actually pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are looking for lambda ? Please provide scenario..

If your input is a List with fast random access, you can solve your problem using the stream of indices:

```
public static List<String> f(int n, List<String> input) {
int fence = IntStream.range(0, input.size())
                     .filter(idx -> input.get(idx).equals("B")) // leave only B's
                     .skip(n-1)
                     .findFirst() // an index of n-th B
                     .getAsInt(); // with throw NoSuchElementException if not enough B's
return input.subList(0, fence+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to understand how to structure your `for` loop?

Wrote a simple `for` to understand your expected result. Is this what you want to achieve?

```
    // Considering we have these lists.. 
    // ArrayList<String> al1 = "IsA","Car","Vehicle","IsA","house","building"..
    // ArrayList<String> al2 = "IsA","house","home"..

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<al1.size(); i+=3) {
        for(int j=0; j<al2.size(); j+=3) {
            if(i+2 < al1.size() && j+2 < al2.size()) {
                if (al1.get(i).equals(al2.get(i)) && al1.get(i+1).equals(al2.get(i+1))) {
                    result.add(al1.get(i));
                    result.add(al1.get(i+1));
                    result.add(al1.get(i+2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and for the second check, i:e. to check for noun2, the condition can be updated to add the new check for noun2 -

```
if (
(al1.get(i).equals(al2.get(i)) && al1.get(i+1).equals(al2.get(i+1))) ||
(al1.get(i).equals(al2.get(i)) && al1.get(i+2).equals(al2.get(i+2)))
) { .. }
```